# Expectation value of the exponential of a quadratic term in fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, path-integral, regularization, effective-field-theory

I have the following relation in [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.659) paper (J.B. Kogut: Introduction to Lattice Gauge Theory and Spin Systems, equation 8.39, page 709) ([RG](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John-Kogut/publication/200104866_An_introduction_to_lattice_gauge_theory_and_spin_systems/links/5bf8421e92851ced67d37584/An-introduction-to-lattice-gauge-theory-and-spin-systems.pdf)), where the author while doing an RG calculation writes
$$\begin{multline}
\int_{\Lambda'<p<\Lambda} \mathcal{D}h(p)\exp\bigg\{-\frac{1}{2} \int(\partial_\mu h)^2 d^2x\bigg\}\exp\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}\int h^2(\partial_\mu\theta)^2 d^2 x\bigg\}
\\= N \exp\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}\langle h^2\rangle_h (\partial_\mu\theta)^2d^2 x\bigg\}, 
\end{multline}\tag{8.39} $$
where $N$ is some normalization constant and $\theta$ is another field. I do not understand how this comes about. Can someone please explain? I thought only expectation values linear in $h$ can be exponentiated as such.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, well, this is the classic seat-of-the-pants stunt Polyakov is famous for, like Landau or Feynman, etc, a formal wisecrack.

The idea is to integrate over a high momentum slice where *h* fluctuates fast, and affects *θ*, (which being slow, hardly budges, so it is constant), for the purposes of this integration slice, as explained below (8.37). Your integral is then a Gaussian measure in that slice producing expectation values of $f(h, \theta)$, assuming
$$
\langle f(h, \theta)\rangle \sim f(\langle h\rangle, \theta),
$$
a not uncommon stunt in those waters, which you'll stumble on in increasing levels of sophistication in RG-land.

Your function *f* is a gaussian which you could expand in *h* and see conditions for trivializing the cumulants, and factorize the higher moments, but let's not go there... It is an intuitive argument mathematicians hysterically shriek at, because they have never heard the music, cursed by perfect pitch.

Comment: So, $\langle f(h,\theta)\rangle \sim f(\langle h\rangle, \theta)$ *is* an assumption?

Comment: Yeah... sleazy but [practical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Cumulants_of_some_continuous_probability_distributions).

Comment: One wonders how [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXBRCeyQ6D4) sounds to them...

Comment: Wait but this means that we must approximate $\langle x^4\rangle \sim \langle x^2\rangle^2$, which is weird?

Comment: Yes, it is. I guess a dandy would compute the corrections here...

Comment: Whatever makes my life easier. Thanks Polyakov.

Comment: I guess, essentially the idea is that, since $\sigma \sim 1/p^2$ is small, therefore $\langle x^{2m} \rangle  \sim \langle x^2\rangle^m$ is an OK approximation. Did I get it right?

Comment: Possibly... experiment with functions and domains...